# why does testConnectionOnCheckout on c3p0 properties is not recover pool when server restarted?

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I have a problem with c3p0 to recover connection pooling when server restardted
here is my config: hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">7</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">53</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

c3p0-config.xml

```
<c3p0-config>
<default-config>
    <!-- Configuring Connection Testing -->
    <!-- property name="automaticTestTable">TEST_EMS_HIBERNATE_CONN</property -->
    <property name="checkoutTimeout">0</property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">false</property>
    <property name="preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>
    <!-- Configuring Recovery From Database Outages -->
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts">0</property>
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay">1000</property>
    <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure">false</property>
    <!-- Configuring to Debug and Workaround Broken Client Apps -->
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout">1800</property>
    <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</property>
</default-config>
```

and on the main class

```
System.setProperty("C3P0_SYS_PROPS", "-Dcom.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.xml=c3p0-config.xml -Dcom.mchange.v2.log.MLog=com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog -Dcom.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog.DE FAULT_CUTOFF_LEVEL=WARNING");
    HibernateUtilsFactory.startTransaction();
    System.out.println("restart server now! after restarted, please enter");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter String");
    dao.save(); //save operation
    HibernateUtilsFactory.commit();
```

that is the probem, after create session, I interupt code by waiting for input, and while code is interupted, I restart mysql server, after restarted, I press enter and code is resuming but connection pool is not recover, is c3p0-config is not loaded successfully ? or there are some config or code, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expecting a recovery within a single hibernate session. That won't happen. A Connection has already been checked out (embedded within the hibernate session), it's in the hand of the client not the pool, and then it is invalidated. c3p0 will recover in the sense that if the DBMS goes down and then comes back up again, when it comes back up, new Connections will become available for new Sessions and the app will work again. However, Sessions already begun and then interrupted midstream when the DBMS went down will still have been permanently broken. (For some DBMS, there may be some configuration that causes Connections to try to reconnect to a DBMS following a break, eg [MySQL auto reconnect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/auto-reconnect.html).)